# How to use selenium IDE python output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-ide

I have tested a selenium test to download file from website in `selenium IDE`. then I have exported this test as python script.
But I dont know how to use this script in a python code.
Here is the output script:

```
# Generated by Selenium IDE
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class Test201401():
  def setup_method(self, method):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.vars = {}
  
  def teardown_method(self, method):
    self.driver.quit()
  
  def test_201401(self):
    time.sleep(10000)
    self.driver.get("LINK to My Download")
    self.driver.set_window_size(550, 691)
    time.sleep(5000)
    elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.ID, "kc-form")
    assert len(elements) > 0
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys("myusername")
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("mypasswor")
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "kc-login").click()
    time.sleep(5000)
```

I have installed `pytest` and `selenium` by `pip3` in windows. Nothing happens after running this script . no Error and no Download!

Comment: No methods are being runned. You never called anything.

Comment: You've only defined your functions/methods here.  Call setup_method, test_201401, then (and you probably need to check for completion of download first) teardown_method.  (I don't know python, so I'm little confused about the "method" arg in the setup and teardown methods there...)

Comment: how should I call my functions in python? for example is it enough to call like this? : `p1=Test201401()` or just `Test201401()` ?

Comment: similar issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63342522/selenium-ide-python-code-export-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Extremely late to the party, but you need to create an instance of class `Test201401`.
Add the following code at the end of your script.

```
inst = Test201401()
inst.setup_method('')
inst.test_201401()
inst.teardown_method('')
```

Refer to Python docs on classes https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes